# In VS Code, How do I format a document (.cpp) so that it converts indentation with N spaces to indentation with M spaces?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, formatting

I am using VS Code to edit C++ source and the document that I'm working on has indentation using `N=2` spaces. I want the indentation to be converted to `M=4` spaces.

This is what appears when I select "Format document with..." in the command panel:

[image]

Here is part of my settings.json:

```
"[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.css-language-features",
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features",
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features",
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "[powershell]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.powershell",
        "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
        "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "[cpp]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd"
    },
```

Here's my status bar (Just showing that I'm set to four spaces):

[image]

Related extensions I have installed:

```
Microsoft C/C++
clangd
CMake
CMakeTools
CodeLLDB
```

Unfortunately despite all of these settings, when I right click on the .cpp document and select "Format Document", it does some formatting but still leaves the tabs at two spaces.

How do I get VSCode to auto-format `N` spaces to `M` spaces? (for me, that's two spaces to four spaces)

Comment: usage of images for your second image is not appropriate here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: Updated the post. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you want to do for just one file, here's a way to do it without reaching for more tools that you may not already be using:

- First make sure the editor knows the indentation is `N` (Ex. 2) spaces: Use `Convert Indentation to Spaces` in the command palette, and then select `N`.
- Use `Convert Indentation to Tabs` in the command palette.
- Change indentation to `M` (Ex. 4) spaces with `Convert Indentation to Spaces` (again), but this time select `M`.
- Use `Convert Indentation to Spaces` in the command palette.

Possibly smarter ways to do it, since they can apply to multiple files at once (but with more setup):

- Look into [editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) and [the corresponding VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig)
- Look into using [Clang Format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) and its [`IndentWidth`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#indentwidth) option.