# VSCode how to change indentation format for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

The code was copy-pasted from outside. I would like to see if I can format this with <indentation with tab size 2>, but my VSCode doesn't want to do that. It draws the lines for the tab size 2 indentation, but doesn't actually format the code in that manner.

On the other hand, somehow it does good job with JS files, but just not with Python files. I'm using autopep8. Is it because I am using autopep8 and autopep8 doesn't let me change indentation easily?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the copy-pasted code use 2 tabs per indentation level? Or does it use 4 spaces per level?

Comment: 4 spaces. I want to try changing that to 2 tabs. So I do "indent using tabs -> 2" but it doesn't change the code format.

Comment: What should it change the code format to? How do you know that it didn't change it to 2 tabs, 2 spaces each?

Comment: The highlighted indentation lines changed to 2 tabs format, from 4 spaces. I would like the code to change their indentation to that....

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve? Isn't the indentation of two tabs in your picture now?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75954165/in-vs-code-how-do-i-format-a-document-cpp-so-that-it-converts-indentation-wi/75954284#75954284

Comment: The highlighted indentation lines are in two tabs but the actual code is in four tabs. You can see that the lines don't match the code.

Comment: Unfortunately the link did not help. I did them but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: So your goal is to have only one tab indent per line, taking up two spaces? Can you provide the code in the picture for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can't be auto formatted because the logic is indentation dependent

- select the 4 spaces before the `def` on line 2
- use `Ctrl+D` as many times until you reach before `return`
- type: `Space` `Space`
- exit Multi Cursor: `Esc`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have set tabsze to 2 spaces, if you want the indentation of each line to be one tab (2 spaces):

1. Select the lines you want to remove indentation
2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

*Also if you want to add indentation, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>*